# Is there a way to define the ansible inventory path inside the playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to find a way to specify the inventory path in a playbook instead of in the ansible.cfg file or by using -i during execution of the playbook. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not possible to define the ansible inventory path inside the playbook.

Quoting from [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings)

> "Ansible supports a few ways of providing configuration variables, mainly through **environment variables, command line switches and an ini file** named ansible.cfg